# So, where am I going now?

Tags: story, computer-puzzle

First there was nothing and my head began,

I've sent my messages, finished and ran

I've sent out my stuff, but where is it?

Okay, I've got it, but ring the bell

And step back one and play your guitar normally.

Now press enter and stand it on the floor.

I'll take a new page and then return,

Switch to the outside then back in.

Escape the chain and take control,

One, two, three, four...

Wait, no I didn't get it!

We are lazy, at the same time

The box we've sent is gone for good

This is because our order was cancelled

And the middle was out of the hood.

The box is gone, so we need another spare

But quick! We have to get out!

I've read between the documents, between the crowds

Between the records, between the ones

And now, yes! I'm going somewhere

I know where it is, but you figure it out there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are going to

> [Space!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g1Sq1Nr58hM)

The clues correspond to

> The [ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/):

First there was nothing and my head began,

> Null (**NUL**), Start of heading (**SOH**)

I've sent my messages, finished and ran

> Start of text (**STX**), End of text (**ETX**), End of transmission (**EOT**)

I've sent out my stuff, but where is it?

> Enquiry (**ENQ**)

Okay, I've got it, but ring the bell

> Acknowledge (**ACK**), Bell (**BEL**)

And step back one and play your guitar normally.

> Backspace (**BS**), Horizontal tab (**TAB**)

Now press enter and stand it on the floor.

> New line (**LF**), Vertical tab (**VT**)

I'll take a new page and then return,

> New page (**FF**), Carriage return (**CR**)

Switch to the outside then back in.

> Shift out (**SO**), Shift in (**SI**)

Escape the chain and take control,

> Data link escape (**DLE**)

One, two, three, four...

> Device control 1, 2, 3, 4 (**DC1, DC2, DC3, DC4**)

Wait, no I didn't get it!

> Negative acknowledge (**NAK**)

We are lazy, at the same time

> Synchronous idle (**SYN**)

The box we've sent is gone for good

> End of transmission block (**ETB**)

This is because our order was cancelled

> Cancel (**CAN**)

And the middle was out of the hood.

> End of medium (**EM**)

The box is gone, so we need another spare

> Substitute (**SUB**)

But quick! We have to get out!

> Escape (**ESC**)

I've read between the documents, between the crowds

> File separator (**FS**), Group separator (**GS**)

Between the records, between the ones

> Record separator (**RS**), Unit separator (**US**)

And now, yes! I'm going somewhere
I know where it is, but you figure it out there.

> Printable characters start here. The first printable character is `' '`, a.k.a. **Space**

Comment: rot13(Lbh tbg Radhvel va gur jebat cynpr, ohg naljnlf, jryy qbar.)